# Using \vspace in articles

Tags: spacing, graphics, floats, eps

Is using a `\vspace{}` command a stable/proper way to remove the white space in the figures while using it in an article?

If not, then can anyone suggest me a quick fix to this?

FYI, I am making `.eps` out of matlab `.fig` files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Take a look at the keys `bb`, `viewport`, and `trim` of the [`graphicx` package](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/graphicx). These might be better/more flexible options for your usage.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. `\vspace` is a rather a last resort way in those cases, so the answer is *no*;-)

Comment: You should convert your figures to .pdf with `epspdf`, it will crop your figures to a correct bounding box — the white space certainly comes from an incorrect bounding box.

Comment: But a .eps is automatically converted to a pdf when pdflatex is used.

Comment: What system do you use? Anyway, converted doesn't mean cropped.

Comment: I am on a MAC now. Somehow it gets taken care of in Windows though.  Feeling noob :D

Answer (score 3):

`\vspace` is in general a last-resort measure, because the required amount of space will usually depend on the image's position in the text. It's much better to crop the original file to remove the offending whitespace. However, if this is not possible, we still have more options provided by the `graphicx` package to remove the excess whitespace without resorting to `\vspace`.

The OP has noted in a comment that `trim` solved the problem at hand. But here are some general examples showing the possibilities. Throughout, I additionally use the `clip` key to prevent overprinting of the clipped area. Remove `clip` if the overprinting is actually desired.

The `viewport` key may be used to specify the area to view. It accepts four values (each in units of `bp` (big (Adobe, PS) points): `viewport = <bottom left x> <bottom left y> <top right x> <top right y>`, where (0,0) is the bottom left corner of the complete image. For example,

```
\includegraphics[viewport=0 0 144 72,clip]{example-image-a}
```

includes the rectangular 2-inch by 1-inch lower-left segment of the source image.

The `trim` key is used to specify how much to crop from each edge. It also accepts four values in units of `bp`: `trim = <left> <bottom> <right> <top>`. So, to trim `1in` from every edge and scale the resulting area to `2in` width, use:

```
\includegraphics[width=2in,trim=72 72 72 72,clip]{example-image-a}
```

Note that the scaling to the specified width is done *after* the trim operation has been applied. That is, `width=2in` will scale the result of the trim to a width of 2 inches.

Here's the complete code for illustration purposes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-a}
\caption{The full image.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[viewport=0 0 144 72,clip]{example-image-a}
\caption{Adjusting the viewport.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2in,trim=72 72 72 72,clip]{example-image-a}
\caption{Trimming the image.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]